# Get url of current path in Terminal SSH

Tags: git, ssh, terminal

I am having trouble using git on my own server. I am having trouble where I add the origin path (remote add) as I am entering the wrong url. By finding out the correct path to the .git repository on my server, I should be able to enter that into `remote add` and it should now find the git repository. So, what I would like to know is how can you get the current path of the folder you are browsing via SSH?

Thanks

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If the remote host is Unix-like, type `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bash script to copy the path to any directory to clipboard

*readlink.sh*

```
readlink -f $1 | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Usage:

- `readlink.sh ./` # current directory
- `readlink.sh /path/to/somewhere/over/the/rainbow`